# How to show QProgressBar smoothly?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qprogressbar

I'm learning `Pyside QProgressBar` on MacOSX. When I use QProgressBar like following, it only indicate 0% or 100%. How to make a QProgressBar smoothly? Is there any way to do this?

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QProgressBar, QWidget
from PySide.QtCore import QTimer
import time

app = QApplication([])
pbar = QProgressBar()
pbar.setMinimum(0)
pbar.setMaximum(100)

pbar.show()

def drawBar():
    global pbar
    pbar.update()

t = QTimer()
t.timeout.connect(drawBar)
t.start(100)

for i in range(1,101):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pbar.setValue(i)

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of this code:

```
for i in range(1,101):   # this won't work, because
    time.sleep(0.1)      # Qt's event loop can't run while
    pbar.setValue(i)     # you are forcing the thread to sleep
```

and instead, add a global variable p:

```
p = 0
```

and increment it in your drawBar() function:

```
def drawBar():
    global pbar
    global p
    p = p + 1
    pbar.setValue(p)
    pbar.update()
```

Comment: I didn't know the while loop force the thread to sleep. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I'll do check mark after few days. Until then please wait... And I already upvoted your answer. Upvoting and Check mark don't hurt me at all.

Answer (score 1):

QPropertyAnimation is easy to use and it does the smooth change for you.

```
    animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(pbar, "value")
    animation.setDuration(???)
    animation.setStartValue(0)
    animation.setEndValue(100)
    animation.start()
```

**Edited post:**

Just replace everything between pbar.show() and app.exec() by the code I suggested

Here is the complete code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QProgressBar, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QPropertyAnimation

app = QApplication([])
pbar = QProgressBar()
pbar.setMinimum(0)
pbar.setMaximum(100)

pbar.show()

animation = QPropertyAnimation(pbar, "value")
animation.setDuration(2000)
animation.setStartValue(0)
animation.setEndValue(100)
animation.start()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is difficult for me. Could you please give me entire code?

Comment: inline `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QProgressBar, QApplication`
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation

    app = QApplication([])
    pbar = QProgressBar()
    pbar.setMinimum(0)
    pbar.setMaximum(100)

    pbar.show()

    animation = QPropertyAnimation(pbar, "value")
    animation.setDuration(2000)
    animation.setStartValue(0)
    animation.setEndValue(100)
    animation.start()

    app.exec_()
`

Comment: the comment box does not help formatting the code... Just replace everything between pbar.show() and app.exec() for the code I suggested

Comment: Thanks. I changed `PyQt` to `PySide` and It worked. Ah I understand what you say, it's animation!

Comment: @SauloT I suggest you extend/update your post instead of posting code in a comment.

Comment: Can this be achieved with `QTimeLine()` as well? I, myself, have given up on `QPropertyAnimation()` since the transitions between `QProgressBar()` values were not smooth at all. Got any experience with `QTimeLine()`?